# Power Query to an Excel file from a Restricted SharePoint Folder

Tags: excel, ms-access, sharepoint, powerquery

Here is the issue I am currently dealing with. I have an excel file that is in a restricted SharePoint folder. Only 3 people can edit the files in the folder. However, I want other people to be able to see the results of file and ideally be able to use them to Vlookup for example. My thought is, I want a new excel sheet that has a query that updates for everyone from the excel file in the restricted folder.

Here is what I have tired:

- simple excel restriction permissions - doesn't work because you cannot import into Power BI then which we also need this file to do
- Query the excel file in the restricted folder to a new excel file that is not restricted. This doesn't work because everyone besides me get a query failed error.
- Upload the excel file to Power BI dataset and then query that data. Issue, only people with Power BI pro can see data
- Put Access DB on Sharepoint, link excel file to the Access DB and then Query the Access DB to a new excel file. Issue: it maps to my local files, not Sharepoint, even though those files are supposed to sync with sharepoint.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [SharePoint permissions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)?

Comment: Yes we are currently using sharepoint permissions to restrict the "master" file access. But those permissions cause a query for everyone to fall